# Strip hidden whitespace from string

Tags: php, string

I have a string with 35 displayed characters but the string's length is 36 due to some kind of whitespace at the end of the string. How can I get rid of this kind of 'hidden' character (whose Hex-Code representation is `08`) ?

`var_dump($string)` gives
`string(36) "2014/08/8609249656_f478108e0e_h.jpg"`

Hex-Code of `$string`: `323031342f30382f383630393234393635365f663437383130386530655f682e6a706708`

Hex-Code of string as desired (without the `08` at the end).
`323031342f30382f383630393234393635365f663437383130386530655f682e6a7067`

I can't just manually shorten the string, cause some strings do not have this 'hidden' character at the end. Also, `trim()` does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add the character to [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim)'s character mask:

```
trim($string, " \t\n\r\0\x0B\x08");
```

Answer (score 3):

The char `0x8` is the `backspace` char. You can use:

```
str_replace("\x08", "", $string);
```

However, while the above code will sanitize the strings, you need to ask yourself: Why does your image names contain backslash characters at all? You should investigate the origin of the problem.

Comment: @hek2mgl I'm not the one who downvoted, but I'd say that a change in the input would break the whole code. So it's correct, but far from good. It's much more an unsure workaround than a good solution. Nevermind you edited.